# Change Computer Icon?

Tags: windows-7, icons

After finding out adding an autorun on a flash drive to change the icon to actually look like your flash drive, then after finding out that it'd work for Hard Drives too, I started to wonder if you could change your whole computer's icon so other computers on your network could actually see your physical computer. I doubt that there's a way to do this, but if there is, it'd be pretty cool. :D

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the icon dislpayed is entirely up to the client OS.